# An error is occurring when im trying to open a filechooser with the click of an image button

Tags: python, kivy

im trying to Load a Filechooser popup when an image button is pressed and pick an image to replace the image in my kivy/python file but I am incurring an error in the code, here is my mre. Any help would be appreciated.

mainfile.py

```
import kivy
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.button import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App



class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    pass


class LoadDialog(FloatLayout):
    load = ObjectProperty(None)
    save = ObjectProperty(None)

class ProfileWindow(Screen):
    load = ObjectProperty(None)
    cancel = ObjectProperty(None)


    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ProfileWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.profileimage = ImageButton(source= "icons/profilepic.png", pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.65})
        self.profileimage.bind(on_release= self.imagechange)
        self.add_widget(self.profileimage)

    def imagechange(self, instance):
        content = LoadDialog(load=self.load_list, cancel=self.dismiss_popup)
        self._popup = Popup(title="Load a file list", content=content, size_hint=(1, 1))
        self._popup.open()

    def load_list(self, path, filename):
        pass

    def dismiss_popup(self):
        self._popup.dismiss()



kv = Builder.load_file("kivy.kv")

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

sm = WindowManager()

sm.current = "page"

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

kivy.kv

```
<WindowManager>:
    id: window_manager
    ProfileWindow:
        id: page
        name: "page"

<ProfileWindow>:

    full_name: fullname
    jobs: jobs

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<LoadDialog>:
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        orientation: "vertical"
        FileChooserListView:
            id: filechooser
            path: './'
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 30
            Button:
                text: "Cancel"
                on_release: root.cancel()
            Button:
                text: "Load"
                on_release: root.load(filechooser.path, filechooser.selection)
```

Any help which could be lent would be appreciated. I am newbie to kivy and python

Comment: Your code doesn't run: `NameError: name 'fullname' is not defined`

Comment: sorry about that, remove "full name and jobs" from the kivy file. didn't add that part in the python code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a `cancel` property in your `LoadDialog` class.
Also, you don't need the `load` and `cancel` properties in your `ProfileWindow` class

Here is your `.py` file fixed:

```py
class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    pass


class LoadDialog(FloatLayout):
    load = ObjectProperty(None)
    save = ObjectProperty(None)
    cancel = ObjectProperty(None)


class ProfileWindow(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ProfileWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.profileimage = ImageButton(source="icons/profilepic.png",
                                        pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.65})
        self.profileimage.bind(on_release=self.imagechange)
        self.add_widget(self.profileimage)

    def imagechange(self, instance):
        content = LoadDialog(load=self.load_list, cancel=self.dismiss_popup)
        self._popup = Popup(title="Load a file list", content=content, size_hint=(1, 1))
        self._popup.open()

    def load_list(self, path, filename):
        self.profileimage.source = filename[0]
        print(path, filename)
        self.dismiss_popup()

    def dismiss_popup(self):
        self._popup.dismiss()


kv = Builder.load_file("kivy.kv")


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


sm = WindowManager()

sm.current = "page"


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```